# не могу решить задачу цыкл for5 абрамян. Дано вещественное число - цена 1 кг конфет. Вывести стоймость 0.1, 0.2, ...1 кг конфет

Tags: kotlin, for, foreach, kotlin-faq, kotlinx

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][![ошибка в 8 ой строке кода. как я могу исправить это?
import java.util.*

fun main() {
var scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)
var x = scanner.nextDouble()
val a: Double = 0.1
val b: Double = 1.0
for (i in a..b) {
println(i*x)
}
}
][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Btn0.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Btn0.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
 for(i in 1..10)
       println(x*i/10)
```